# How to determine a pattern from a series of latitude and longitudes

Tags: geospatial, latitude-longitude

Given a series of latitudes and longitudes, I want to determine programmatically if that contains a closed loop at all or not.

Is there a way I can determine this? I know this involves techniques within the Geospatial area, but I am unaware of it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you add a few more details on regarding language/system you're targetting? For example, in SQL Server, you can check if a a linestring is closed with STIsClosed (which basically means the start and end points are the same)

Comment: Let's say a man is traveling from point A to point B. He could go straight to point B or do some loops along the way. Given that I know the lat-long of numerous points along his route, my intent was to find out if there was indeed a closed loop shape on his path. Java is my preferred way, but I don't mind using anything else as long as I can achieve this functionality.

Comment: OK, (and I'm no expert) but what I think you're after is to create a linestring from your points and then determine if it self-intersects. The OGC term for this is 'Simple' and in SQL Server this is STIsSimple (I think it's something like ST_IsSimple in PostGIS) Not familiar with any Java GIS libraries but hopefully this will help you find something.

Comment: Thanks Les. I will do some reading.